# vim alternate color/shade of rows/lines based on grouping criteria

Tags: vim, colors, highlighting

I have a file that is similar to the output of md5sum, i.e., it contains rows/lines of the following form:

```
9803f392bb3f89f1c20bbc9baec8483a /some/path/file1
9803f392bb3f89f1c20bbc9baec8483a /some/other/path/file1
4ca001c5586eb0744e3174bc75c6fba8 /a/certain/path/file2
4ca001c5586eb0744e3174bc75c6fba8 /another/path/file2
4ca001c5586eb0744e3174bc75c6fba8 /some/different/path/file2withadifferentname
78753e869231cc1417a92eebaa076718 /and/so/on/file3
78753e869231cc1417a92eebaa076718 /and/so/forth/file
78753e869231cc1417a92eebaa076718 /something/like/that
```

Assume the file is sorted according to md5sums (i.e., the first 32 characters). I would like to view this file in vim with alternate coloring of lines, such that same color is assigned to files with same md5sums.

This could be considered a special case of grouping of lines based on some crieteria (in this case the criteria being same string in the first 32 characters compared to previous line).

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting with multi-line matches might be expensive and noticeably slow down Vim; additionally, I don't know how to get that alternating effect. But it is pretty easy to define folding of those lines that have the same checksum:

```
:setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=matchstr(getline(v:lnum),'^\\x\\+')==matchstr(getline(v:lnum+1),'^\\x\\+')?1:'<1'
```

See `:h fold-expr` for details.